# Prove$\sum_{|\alpha|<1, f(\alpha)=0}\log \frac{1}{|\alpha|}= \sum_{\Re(\rho)>1/2}\log\ |\frac{\rho}{1-\rho}|$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

Let
$$ f(z)= (s-1)\zeta(s) $$
where $s=\frac{1}{1-z}$ and $\zeta$ denotes the Riemann Zeta function.

Prove that,$$\sum_{|\alpha|<1, f(\alpha)=0}\log \frac{1}{|\alpha|}= \sum_{\Re(\rho)>1/2}\log\ \left|\frac{\rho}{1-\rho}\right|$$
I found this in [this paper](https://labs.thosgood.com/builds/AIM-143-1999-284.pdf) of Balazard Saias and Yor-.

**My try**- I have understood the whole paper but this one line i could not get.

Comment: @vitamin d Thanks for the edit. Please answer.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @vitamin d Thanks for such a prompt edit.

Comment: @vitamin d I have read the whole paper. I am struck in this line which is my question

Comment: @vitamin d Pg 285 last line of this paper is my question.

Comment: Wow this is a french paper. Let me *try* to read it.

Comment: @vitamin d Here is its english version. https://thosgood.com/translations/

Comment: @vitamin D you can upvote my question please.

Comment: Anandita Kumari Aka @ShekharSuman I have replaced the French paper with the English one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very elementary math as below:

Let: $\rho=\frac{1}{1-\alpha}$

Then $1/\rho=1-\alpha$, so $\alpha=\frac{\rho-1}{\rho}$, so $1/\alpha=\frac{\rho}{\rho-1}$ so $|1/\alpha|=|\frac{\rho}{\rho-1}|=|\frac{\rho}{1-\rho}|$
Since $f(\alpha)=0$ corresponds to $\zeta(\rho)=0$ and of course $|\alpha| <1$ corresponds to $\Re \rho > 1/2$ the result should be clear now.

As an aside, the above is part of the proof of the Balazard Saias Yor criterion (which itself is part of a large number of integral criteria equivalences to RH, but it looks simpler so it has more appeal to amateurs) to prove/disprove the Riemann Hypothesis using the formula proved in the mentioned paper:

$\int_{\Re s =1/2}\frac{\log |\zeta(s)|}{|s|^2}d|s|=2 \pi\sum_{\Re(\rho)>1/2, \zeta(\rho)=0}\log\ \left|\frac{\rho}{1-\rho}\right| $

so in particular the integral is zero iff RH is true

Comment: Thank you so much for a beautiful answer.